# What does 70% grey mean and how do I specify this in UIColor?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicolor

I'd like to replicate the default color of the UITextField placeholder field. From the documentation:

> The placeholder string is drawn using a 70% grey color.

1. What does 70% mean in this statement?
2. What is the best way to initialize UIColor with this color, preferably in a way that shows the color is "70% grey"?

Comment: I guess 255*0.7 for all channels except alpha.

Comment: Well in the world of photography when you use a gray card, the percentage indicates how much light is reflected. So yeah my guess is the same as @beryllium.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is 70% grey:

```
UIColor* grey70 = [UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.70 alpha:1];
```

It is white but only 70% of the maximum brightness (1.0).

1.0 is pure white,
0.5 is middle grey,
0.0 is black.

Comment: just a comment... on iOS7, it's actually closer to [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1.0]

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I've found grabbing it from its derived property(iOS 7):

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.098/255.0 alpha:0.22]
```

Answer (score 6):

I have been trying to get a UILabel I created to match the placeholder text all day and 70% gray was not working.

I tried:

```
[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.70 alpha:1.0]
```

What I ended up finding as the closest was

```
0xC7C7CD
```

Comment: This was not a question... this was an answer. The original requestor was trying to find the default color of the placeholder text and believed it to be 70%. I was sharing my experience as an answer saying that 70% was not what I found to be the color but infact it was 0xC7C7CD. Please remove the - rep after reading this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a textView, the following works very well with Swift:

```
let placeholderTextColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.21)

let placeholderBorderColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.21).CGColor
textView.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(0.5)
textView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(5)
```